# Write at the end of an xml

Tags: java, xml, xslt

i have multiple Xml files, in a `List<File>`. What i want  is to transform those xml into one Xml with an Xsl :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="testsuites">
    <xsl:call-template name="summary"/>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="summary">
           <xsl:variable name="testCount" select="sum(testsuite/@tests)"/>
         <xsl:variable name="errorCount" select="sum(testsuite/@errors)"/>
         <xsl:variable name="failureCount" select="sum(testsuite/@failures)"/>
 <xsl:variable name="timeCount" select="sum(testsuite/@time)"/>
         <xsl:variable name="successRate" select="($testCount - $failureCount - $errorCount) div $testCount"/>
          <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$failureCount &gt; 0">Failure</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$errorCount &gt; 0">Error</xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:attribute>
         <Build>
          <NombreTest><xsl:value-of select="$testCount"/></NombreTest>
          <Failures><xsl:value-of select="$failureCount"/></Failures>
          <Erreurs><xsl:value-of select="$errorCount"/></Erreurs>
         <PercentSucces><xsl:call-template name="display-percent">
                    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$successRate"/>
                </xsl:call-template></PercentSucces>
          <ExecTime><xsl:call-template name="display-time">
                   <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$timeCount"/>
                </xsl:call-template> </ExecTime>
          </Build> 
       </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="failure">
    <xsl:call-template name="display-failures"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="error">
    <xsl:call-template name="display-failures"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="display-time">
    <xsl:param name="value"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($value,'0.000')"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="display-percent">
    <xsl:param name="value"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($value,'0.00%')"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="display-failures">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(@message)">N/A</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="@message"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My problem is that when i am looping and apply the transform with a `TransformerFactory` it always erase the output XML. I want to edit the output instead.

I know that i can do it in java with a temporary XML and after merge it, but i'm almost sure that it is possible in XSL?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you want to run your transformation against several input document? Or do you want to access several input document from one transformation?

Comment: i want to run the transformation for multiple (same structure, same stylesheet ) xml and put the result in one xml

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and a typical solution. Additionally you need to find out from the documentation of your XSLT processor how to pass parameters to the transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to pass all document URLs within a single external parameter and you will typically have a transformation like this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 
 <xsl:param name="pdocNames">
  <name>doc1.xml</name>
  <name>doc2.xml</name>
  <name>doc3.xml</name>
 </xsl:param>
 
    <!-- you can directly use $pdocNames/name
        if the param is provided externally -->
 <xsl:variable name="vDocNames" select=
  "document('')/*/xsl:param[]@name='pdocNames']/name"/>
    
 <xsl:template match="/">
     <combinedDocs>
    <xsl:copy-of select="document($vDocNames)"/>
     </combinedDocs>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), it performs the following**:

1. **Obtains the `name` elements that contain the provides in the parameter `$pdocNames` document URIs**. These elements are contained in the variable `vDocNames`.
2. **Creates the top element for the output document** (in this case named `combinedDocs`).
3. **Copies all XML documents, whose URIs are in the `name` elements contained in the `vDocNames` variable**. The standard XSLT function **[`document()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#document)** is used here.

**Do note**:

The URLs of all wanted XML documents must be passed externally via a parameter to the transformation. It is vendor-dependent how to pass a parameter to the transformation. You need to read the documentation provided for your particular XSLT processor.

Comment: thanks a lot, it is really helping. But about the 'name' element,     I have a list of path but it's not in an xlm with element. i can put in parameter something like this :  
[/Users/admin/Documents/testxml/20101119-2254/20101122-1255/TESTS-TestSuites.xml, /Users/admin/Documents/testxml/20101119-2254/TESTS-TestSuites.xml,...]

Comment: maybe i could create the xml listing all files, seems that it is the most simple

Comment: @Theo: Yes, this is another solution -- especially when the files are statically known. As for passing a parameter that contains an XML element or an XML fragment -- yes, this should be possible. It certainly is possible for XslCompiledTransform in .NET

Answer (score 0):

You have to load your documents with document(URI) XSLT function

See also: http://www.w3schools.com/Xsl/func_document.asp